# Set default value to react-select in update form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-select

I'm fairly new to react

I'm trying it write an update form with react-select
and i have a trouble to set the default selection

```
  let flight = useLocation();
  if (flight.state) {
    flight = flight.state.flightobj
  }
```

is the flight data that needed to be updated ( taken from previous page)

```
(airlineOptions?.find(({ label }) => label === flight?.airline)
```

Find the option and format it for select

The problem is that it just wont set the default, i tried to do set `{label, value}` manually and it works.

Second problem
`onSubmit` prop in the `select` not firing for some reason. `onSubmit` form wise does. I excluded `onSubmit` from the code .

```js
const CreateFlightForm = () => {
  let flight = useLocation();
  if (flight.state) {
    flight = flight.state.flightobj
  }

  let [airlineOptions, setAirlineOptions] = useState()
  let [airline, setAirline] = useState()
  let [opt, setOpt] = useState(airlineOptions ? .find(({
    label
  }) => label === flight ? .airline));


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... sends to db

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAirlines()
  }, [])


  // let defaultval = () => {
  //   let test = airlineOptions?.find(({ label }) => label === flight?.airline)
  //   // console.log(test);
  //   setOpt(test)
  // }


  let getAirlines = async() => {
    let response = await fetch(`/backend/airlines`)
    let data = await response.json()
    setAirlineOptions(data.map((airline) => ({
      value: airline.id,
      label: airline.name
    })))

  }


  return ( <
    div className = 'create' >
    <
    FormHeader headercheck = {
      flight
    }
    /> <
    form id = 'app_form'
    onSubmit = {
      (e) => handleSubmit(e)
    } >
    <
    label > Airline < /label>               <
    Select required id = 'airline'
    isClearable = {
      true
    }
    options = {
      airlineOptions
    }
    defaultValue = {
        opt
     }

    isSearchable = {
      true
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => {
        if (e) setAirline(e.value)
      }
    }
            defaultValue = {opt}

    /> <
    input type = 'submit' > < /input>


    <
    /form>

    <
    /div>



  )

}

export default CreateFlightForm
```